# Building multiple .msi, that have a diffrent config file with TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs, wix, azure-devops

I'm facing challenges where 3 customers need to connect to some WebAPI. All three of them have a different URL, and this URL is kept inside .config file. I would like to create .MSI for each of three customer where would have a different URL in config, already in build.

I'm using Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2018 and Wix Toolset.

Do you have any idea how to accomplish this or maybe some other suggestions for me?

Comment: What is your current build pipeline?

Comment: So far, just one pipeline, I'm only having default build values from config file.

Comment: In the build pipeline, you can add 3 tasks to create .msi files, each task have his configuration.